# Sharepoint 2013 flowchart workflow custom code

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, codebehind

I'am SharePoint 2013 beginner and i have a project where i need to create a workflow (**With Visual Studio**), so i started my workflow as flowchart workflow then at some point i needed to write custom code (like to get something from DB) but couldn't find anyway to do that (i can't call the class's functions), whereas in 2010's sequential workflow the wf already has a code behind class.

So my question is: Is there anyway i could call custom code like in sequential workflows !?

Note: I already added a class and tried to use "InvokeMethod" with it, but couldn't reach the class's functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way to call some code is by using the HttpSend activity and call a custom webservice

Comment: thanks for your answer, I can't vote it up unfortunately (due to lack of reputation), but I've marked it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Abdessamad TAHRI said, you cannot use code in Visual Studio for SharePoint 2013 workflows. Workflows are declarative now and you would need to expose whatever data you need from that database to a web service that you can call in the workflow.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I can't vote it up unfortunately (due to lack of reputation), but thanks a lot.

Comment: That's ok - happy to help!